# Preserving trailing slashes of prerequisites in GNU Make 3.81

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider this very simple makefile:

```
foo: bar/
```

Running GNU Make 3.81 on this makefile results in:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `bar', needed by `foo'. Stop.
```

As we can see, the trailing `/` is removed from `bar/`.

Alternatively, using the [`--print-data-base` or `-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) option to print the rules resulting from processing this makefile:

```
$ make -p 2>/dev/null | grep foo:
foo: bar
```

We can see that the trailing slash is removed from the original `bar/`. This issue, however, is not present in newer versions of GNU Make (e.g., 4.2.1).

How can I preserve the trailing slash in the name of a rule's prerequisites in GNU Make 3.81?

Comment: You must first update to the latest make, make-3.81 is 13 years old.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I wish I could.

Comment: There were serious bugs fixed since then. What stops you?

Comment: Short and simple answer: you can't.  Slightly longer answer: you can download the source code and change it then use that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain trailing `/` doesn't seem to be possible, but maybe `bar/.` will help you? It would require to rewrite all directory targets to include the trailing `/.`

```
_empty :=
_space := $(_empty) $(_empty)

.PHONY: bar bar/.
bar bar/.:
       @echo "$@ -> $(dir $@)"

foo: bar/

foo_quoted: "bar/ "

foo_space: bar/$(_space)

foo_space_quoted: "bar/$(_space)"

BAR = "bar/ "

foo_var: $(BAR)

BAR_DIR = bar/

foo_dir: $(dir $(BAR_DIR))

BAR_SPACE = bar/$(_space)

foo_var_space: $(BAR_SPACE)

foo_dot: bar/.

foo_double: bar//
```

All other attempts will look for `bar`, i.e. GNU make strips the trailing `/` when processing the dependencies either during parsing or execution. The `foo_dot` example on the other hand results in

```
$ ./make --version
GNU Make 3.81
...
$ ./make foo_dot
bar/. -> bar/

$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
...
$ make foo_dot
bar/. -> bar/
```